# Solr search with a single round bracket not working

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I am new to Solr.

I am trying to search for records containing single round bracket either '(' or ')'.

The query for searching the record is as follows:

```
q=( ( name: (*\(abc*) ) )
```

The above query breaks the solr search.

I am escaping the ( ) character by using the following regex:

```
value = value.replace(/([()])/g, '\\$1');
```

Can someone please help to troubleshoot this issue ?

Comment: Basically looking for contains query with parenthesis.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks the solr search"? Crash, error, zero hits?

The query that @Persimmonium suggests is fine, so your problem might be that your analyzer removes parentheses. Check this by doing a `name:known\)word` search followed by `name:known\)word*`. If the last one doesn't give a hit, your analyzer probably removes `)`. You can also do it through _Analysis_ in the GUI, which will tell you more (and might be more confusing).

Comment: As I understand from your question, you need only '(' or ')' not both. Following query would serve the purposes `name: *\(* OR name:*\)* NOT  name:*\(*\)*`

Answer (score 2):

I am not very good with the regex so I cannot discern what is happening there, but this solr query should work:

```
q=name:*\(abc*
```

does it no?

As you can see [in the lucene doc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters), the only char to escape in your query is (. ) would need to be escaped too if you search for it. But I understand in your example all the ) are just part of the language.